# Can't use constraints for cell with .xib file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, storyboard

I need to set constraints for a UILabel, but whenever I try to add a constraint for my UITableViewCell it messes up, and the element goes to the top left corner it seems
[Here's how I set up my UI elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9Tl8.png)

[Here's how it looks like when I run in a simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVo9b.png)
"Food" is the "English Meaning" UILabel

Here's my code for the cell file that's generated with the xib

```
class ReusableCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var arabicMeaning: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var englishMeaning: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var upvoteButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var downvoteButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var upvoteCount: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var downvoteCount: UILabel!

var upFlag = true
var downFlag = true

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
static func nib() -> UINib{
    return UINib(nibName: K.ReusableCell, bundle: nil)
}


@IBAction func ReviewPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if upFlag && downFlag{
        if sender == upvoteButton{
            upvoteCount.text = String(Int(upvoteCount.text!)! + 1)
        }
        else {
            downvoteCount.text = String(Int(downvoteCount.text!)! + 1)
        }
    }
    else if sender == upvoteButton && upFlag{
        upFlag = false
        downFlag = true
        upvoteCount.text = String(Int(upvoteCount.text!)! + 1)
    }
    else if sender == downvoteButton && downFlag{
            upFlag = true
            downFlag = false
        downvoteCount.text = String(Int(downvoteCount.text!)! + 1)
        }
    
}
```

}

Comment: How did you create your cell XIB? The "built-in" `Content View` should have no constraints to the safe-area. And, all of you UI elements should be constrained to the Content View (it looks like you've constrained them to the cell itself?).

Comment: I solved the issue by deleting the whole xib file and the swift file that's attached to it
Then made another files, copies the data from the old swift file to it
And carefully put new components inside the new xib file and connected them to the swift file and it worked, maybe I messed up a component with the old xib file idk